# CSS word-wrap on all elements

Tags: css, word-wrap

One of our QA guys found a bug that within fieldsets where long words would break out of the element. I fixed that with a simple word-wrap: break-word. But then they found another one. And another. And another.

I could have a long argument with him where I say that this is a dumb bug because no user is going to enter a 60-letter word, but it's probably easier just to fix it. What are your thoughts on doing

```
* { word-wrap: break-word }
```

I don't know of any problems this would cause.

Edit: there are several places this appears, in several different contexts.

In some places it looks like this:

```
<fieldset>
  <p>Here_is_a_really_long_string</p>
</fieldset>
```

Another place we've found this:

```
<table>
..
<td>Here_is_a_really_long_string</td>
```

I think the biggest places we're seeing are really long URL strings and places where the RSS feed we're importing this from has data such as here_is_a_string.

I'll talk to the QA/Project manager but I don't know how the client will feel about an ellipsis.

Comment: Can we see more of the code to provide some context?

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict the width of the area and add some "..." at the end.
Try this

```
.truncate {
  width: 250px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use overflow:hidden where needed. You don't want to override default element word-wrapping.

Comment: Do you have a specific reason not to want it though? My project manager said they didn't want to hide the content.

Comment: If it's erroneous content, why would you need to show it? Granted, I can't answer that question for you.

Comment: Another solution would be to truncate with ellipsis and add a title tag. Should the user mouseover the content, it would display the full line. 

Just an idea.

Answer (score 0):

In English, 60 letter words are not very common, but in other languages that may not be the case. So it depends a little on how your software is going to be used and who is responsible for that content.

If you fix it like you do, I would at least use a more specific selector and apply the wrapping only to a specific form or other relevant part of the page instead of all elements.

Also, I'd talk to the Q&A guy. Maybe they agree that this isn't a real problem after all, although I'd be more careful than to call it a 'dumb bug' if you want to get them on your side. :)
But even if they insist it should be fixed, maybe they have some idea of *how* it should be fixed. Maybe `overflow: hidden` or the use of ellipsis is acceptable, or maybe they think it's best to use word wrapping anyway to make sure all text is visible.

Anyway, in most cases, the fastest solution is to have the discussion anyway. A little chat is usually more constructive than communication through pull requests.